# Increment numerical value inside the string

Tags: javascript, regex

Facing issue with incrementing value in which i have to increment numerical string value.

```js
var text = "SYN00099";
var getPart = text.replace(/[^\d.]/g, ''); // returns 00099
var num = parseInt(getPart); // returns 99
var newVal = num + 1; // returns 100
var reg = new RegExp(num.toString()); // create dynamic regexp
var newstring = text.replace(reg, newVal.toString()); // returns SYN000100
console.log(num);
console.log(newVal);
console.log(reg);
console.log(newstring);
```

this what i tried in my code. This works properly but the problem with this code it increase the string length if number going to increase. as example if it's last digit is 9 then it changes to 10 but it does not remove 1 zero from the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having the increment, you can fill '0' in front of the `num + 1` string by using [String.padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) function as follows.

```
var newVal = (num + 1).toString().padStart(getPart.length, '0'); // returns 00100
```

Using that function, it will fill `0` two times in front of `100` string (so the total length = 5 = `getPart string length`)

Below is working example.

```js
var text = "SYN00099";
var getPart = text.replace(/[^\d.]/g, ''); // returns 00099
var num = parseInt(getPart); // returns 99
var newVal = (num + 1).toString().padStart(getPart.length, '0'); // returns 00100
var newstring = text.replace(getPart, newVal); // returns SYN000100
console.log(num);
console.log(newVal);
console.log(newstring);
```

Comment: This is unnecessary bulky code. Should opt for my solution below.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a return function in your regex

```js
"SYN00099".replace(/(0*)(\d+)/, ($0, $1, $2) => $1 + (Number($2) + 1));
```

To ensure fixed number of 5 for example.
it will only every go upto 10 if its 9. So replace 09 with the new number to
keep the fixed number. Although be  mindful that if your number goes upt to SYN99999 it won't update anymore as that's your max

```
"SYN00099".replace(/(09+$|[1-8]\d*|0$)/, ($0, $1) => Number($1) + 1);
```

Its better to use a functional approach like this as its more descriptive, encapsulated in one line and ultimately less boilerplate code.

Comment: It doesn't work as requested. It produces the same wrong result as OP has `"SYN000100"` instead of `"SYN00100"`

Comment: So you only want max 5 numbers?

Comment: OP's problem was adding more characters than the initial had. So, the result should be the same length but the number within also increased by one.

Comment: In that case this: "SYN00099".replace(/(09|[1-8])(\d*)/, ($0, $1, $2) => Number($1 + $2) + 1);

Comment: `SYN00099 -> SYN00100`, however `SYN00098 -> SYN0099` - non `99` numbers that start with `9` will lose one digit.

Answer (score 2):

You could match the number on the end, get the length, parse it, increment, and then return the modified version with the prefix.

```js
const increment = (str) => {
  const [ , prefix, version ] = str.match(/^(\D+)(\d+)$/);
  if (version) {
    const padding = version.length, numeric = parseInt(version, 10);
    return `${prefix}${('' + (numeric + 1)).padStart(padding, '0')}`
  } else {
    return str;
  }
};

console.log(increment('SYN00099'));
```

Here it is in one line:

```js
const increment = (str) => 
  (([ , prefix, version ]) =>
    version
      ? ((padding, numeric) =>
          `${prefix}${('' + (numeric + 1)).padStart(padding, '0')}`)
        (version.length, numeric = parseInt(version, 10))
      : str)
  (str.match(/^(\D+)(\d+)$/));

console.log(increment('SYN00099'));
```

Comment: this return `SYN000910`.

Comment: @Ashish That is because I messed with my expression, sorry.

Comment: If you make it properly i'll just give one upvote for providing support.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`String#replace` and pass a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) in order to handle any where a number might appear within the string:

```js
function increaseNumberInString(text) {
  return text.replace(
    /(\d+)/g, //match any sequence of digits
    function(match, value) {
      const num = parseInt(value); //convert to a number

      return String(num + 1) //increase by one and turn to a string
        .padStart(value.length, "0");  //pad with zeroes back to the initial length
    });
}

console.log("SYN00078 ->", increaseNumberInString("SYN00078"));
console.log("SYN00079 ->", increaseNumberInString("SYN00079"));
console.log("SYN00098 ->", increaseNumberInString("SYN00098"));
console.log("SYN00099 ->", increaseNumberInString("SYN00099"));

console.log("00078ZZ ->", increaseNumberInString("00078ZZ"));
console.log("00079ZZ ->", increaseNumberInString("00079ZZ"));
console.log("00098ZZ ->", increaseNumberInString("00098ZZ"));
console.log("00099ZZ ->", increaseNumberInString("00099ZZ"));

console.log("SYN00078ZZ ->", increaseNumberInString("SYN00078ZZ"));
console.log("SYN00079ZZ ->", increaseNumberInString("SYN00079ZZ"));
console.log("SYN00098ZZ ->", increaseNumberInString("SYN00098ZZ"));
console.log("SYN00099ZZ ->", increaseNumberInString("SYN00099ZZ"));

console.log("SYN00078AA079XX ->", increaseNumberInString("SYN00078AA079XX"));
console.log("SYN00079AA098XX ->", increaseNumberInString("SYN00099AA078XX"));
console.log("SYN00078AA099XX ->", increaseNumberInString("SYN00078AA099XX"));
console.log("SYN00099AA078XX ->", increaseNumberInString("SYN00099AA078XX"));
console.log("SYN00098AA099XX ->", increaseNumberInString("SYN00098AA099XX"));
console.log("SYN00099AA098XX ->", increaseNumberInString("SYN00099AA098XX"));
```